# How Configure EasyMock Class Extension 3.1?

Tags: java, configure, easymock

I want to add  EasyMock Class Extension 3.1 to my project and I have a problem with dependencies of EasyMock 3.1 CE. I add dependencies : cglib-2.2.2.jar and asm-4.0.jar and throws exception :

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

When I use cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar and asm-4.0.jar throws another exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objenesis/ObjenesisHelper
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjenesisClassInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisClassInstantiator.java:26)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:219)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:70)
```

How do I configure EasyMock Class Extension 3.1? What dependencies do I need to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easymock extension 3.1 depends upon easymock 3.1, the dependencies are:

1. cglib: cglib-nodep 2.2.2
2. org.objenesis: objenesis 1.2

from [Maven Easymock](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.easymock/easymock/3.1).

If you're using maven, then the following dependency will work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
    <artifactId>easymockclassextension</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

From version 3.0 there is no longer any need to import *classextension*. Simply do search and replace of all `org.easymock.classextension.*` with `org.easymock.*` and just import the "plain" easymock dependency (see the [EasyMock 3.0 doc](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_ClassExtension_Documentation.html)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
    <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Moreover, if you use Maven, you can use the command

> mvn dependency:tree

to see all dependencies (transitive as well as non-transitive).