# Mocking a concrete class in junit 3

Tags: java, testing, mocking, junit3

I have a class which has the following constructor:

```
class Foo {
    Foo (Bar bar) {
       ...
    }
}
```

I am attempting to write a unit test for this class and Mock out the dependency on Bar. However, I have to use **JUnit 3** and **Bar is a concrete type**. Does anyone have any ideas? I cannot use EasyMock class-extension (requires JUnit 4) and haven't had success with Mockito. One (particularly ugly) solution I am considering is as follows:

```
interface IBarWrapper {
    void barMethod();
}

class BarWrapper implements IBarWrapper {
    void barMethod() {
        bar.barMethod();
    }
}

class Foo {
    Foo (IBarWrapper wrapper) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I don't like the idea of changing my actual code to suit the tests.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?! I guess because I don't have a ranking of 6655 :) . I think this is the best bet. Add this as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just subclass `Bar`.  No need to over complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

With [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/) (v3.x) you are able to mock concrete class. See [Readme](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me (NoClassDefFoundError org/objenesis/ObjenesisHelper). I think I will go for Garrett's suggestion. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Some dependencies are missing. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258797/how-configure-easymock-class-extension-3-1